# How can I tell if sheet a exists in a workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have the following code that's not working as expected:

```
If Sheets("a") <> "" Then MsgBox ("sheet a exists")
```

How can I tell if sheet a exists in the workbook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd make a separate function for it:

```
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String)
    On Error GoTo no:
    WorksheetName = Worksheets(SheetName).Name
    SheetExists = True
    Exit Function
no:
    SheetExists = False
End Function
```

Then you can easily call it where needed, even in a formula if you wanted:

```
Sub ABC()
    If SheetExists("Test") Then
        MsgBox "Yay!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Boo!"
    End If
End Sub
```

or

```
=If(SheetExists("Test"),"Yay!","Boo")
```

Comment: The use of GoTo and labels in structured programming is considered bad form and can usually be avoided with a little extra thought.

Comment: @AndrewP. VBA error handling consists of GoTo or Resume, both of these are far from wonderful, but I've always felt I have more control over a GoTo than a Resume as a Resume could easily pass unnoticed without a conditional check on an error result. I'm always willing to learn though, so I'm looking forward to seeing your answer on the correct way to handle this :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
Sub DoesSheetExist()
    Dim s As Worksheet

    For Each s In Sheets
        If s.Name = "a" Then
            MsgBox "Sheet a exists"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next s
    MsgBox "Sheet a does not exist"
End Sub
```

Comment: I like the descriptive sub name =)

Comment: @Jonno ....................it's fixed................

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the error.  eg:

```
Dim A As String
    On Error Resume Next
        A = Worksheets("a").Name
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 9
                MsgBox "Sheet ""a"" does not exist"
            Case 0
                MsgBox "Sheet ""a"" exists"
            Case Else
                Stop
        End Select
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In the template that I made for AutoFilter, I used a function and procedure to check whether a worksheet is available. In the codes below, it is checked whether the DATA sheet is in the workbook :

```
Sub Sht_Cntrl()
    If Not Sheet_Exists_Cntrl("DATA") Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add( _
    After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "DATA"
    End If
 End Sub

Function Sheet_Exists_Cntrl(SheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet
    On Error GoTo eHandle
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
    Sheet_Exists_Cntrl = True
    Exit Function
eHandle:
    Sheet_Exists_Cntrl = False
End Function
```

When the Sht_Cntrl procedure is called (`Call Sht_Cntrl`) it is created if DATA sheet does not exist.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0ntk.gif)

You can view the codes by downloading the sample template from this page : [Vba autofilter with listbox](https://eksi30.com/filtering-in-worksheet-using-list-boxes/)

Answer (score -1):

```
If (Worksheets("a").Name <> "") Then MsgBox ("sheet A exists")
```

this works as expected

Comment: Unless it doesn't exist, then it may throw a subscript out of range error?